# Why not an expression

Tags: angular

I am learning angular2 have question about `ngStyle`. Consider following code:

```
<div>
  <span [ngStyle]="{color: 'red'}" [style.font-size.px]="fontSize">
    red text
  </span>
</div>
```

Why does `[style.font-size.px]="fontSize"` do not need `{{}}`? Like:

```
 <div>
  <span [ngStyle]="{color: 'red'}" [style.font-size.px]="{{fontSize}}">
    red text
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *interpolation* (`{{…}}`) and *binding* (`[…]`, `(…)`, `[(…)]`) use the "template expression" syntax.

If you wanted a literal value for a binding you should* do

```
[foo]="'strValue'"
```

IOW: binding expressions, already require "template expressions"

Have a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

*) read Günter's comment below

Comment: Some consider it bad practice but `foo="strValue"` would work as well. I would also add that `{}` in `ngStyle` is not related to `{{}}` at all. The former is object literal syntax, the later is Angular2 string value binding syntax.

Comment: you are right. I wish that could be disabled as it has caused me already many headaches with typos (updated the post to refer to your (important) comment.